# Java bitshift strangeness

Tags: java, debugging, bit-shift

Java has 2 bitshift operators for right shifts:

```
>> shifts right, and is dependant on the sign bit for the sign of the result

>>> shifts right and shifts a zero into leftmost bits
```

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

This seems fairly simple, so can anyone explain to me why this code, when given a value of -128 for bar, produces a value of -2 for foo:

```
byte foo = (byte)((bar & ((byte)-64)) >>> 6);
```

What this is meant to do is take an 8bit byte, mask of the leftmost 2 bits, and shift them into the rightmost 2 bits. Ie:

```
initial = 0b10000000 (-128)
-64 = 0b11000000
initial & -64 = 0b10000000
0b10000000 >>> 6 = 0b00000010
```

The result actually is -2, which is

```
0b11111110
```

Ie. 1s rather than zeros are shifted into left positions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the & is actually performing promotion to `int` - which leaves an awful lot of "1" bits. You're then shifting right, leaving the leftmost 2 bits as 0, but then ignoring those leftmost bits by casting back to byte.

This becomes clearer when you separate out the operations:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte bar = -128;
        int tmp = (bar & ((byte)-64)) >>> 6;
        byte foo = (byte)tmp;
        System.out.println(tmp);
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

prints

```
67108862
-2
```

So to do your bit arithmetic again:

```
initial = 0b10000000 (-128)
-64 = 0b11000000
initial & -64 = 0b11111111111111111111111110000000 // it's an int now
0b10000000 >>> 6 = 0b00111111111111111111111111100000 // note zero-padding
(byte) (0b10000000 >>> 6) = 11100000 // -2
```

Even if you get the right result out of the & operation (by casting at that point), `>>>` will promote the first operand to `int` first anyway.

EDIT: The solution is to change how you mask things. Instead of masking by -64, mask by just 128+64=192=0xc0 instead:

```
byte foo = (byte)((bar & 0xc0) >>> 6);
```

That way you really only get left with the two bits you want, instead of having a load of 1s in the most significant 24 bits.

Comment: @Martin: No, because shifting would do the promotion too. Will edit with a solution in a minute.

Comment: Thankyou very much, clearly your bitfoo is greater than mine ;)

Comment: Note, the >>> should be unnecessary here because the sign bits have already been cleared.  Also, the original poster wanted the top two bits which is 0xC0.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, in Java most operators (+,-,>>,& etc.) can't work on anything smaller than `int`s. So, your bitwise shifts and `&` are implicitly casting the values into `int` in the background and then back into `byte` by your explicit cast outside. The last cast gets rid of the zeroes in the higher bits.

To get results you would expect, try doing this on `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

Others have told you why but I'll break it down further and provide an answer to the real problem, too.

```
byte foo = (byte)((bar & ((byte)-64)) >>> 6);
```

Since the & operator will promote everything to int, what this does is essentially:

```
byte foo = (byte)(((int)bar & (int)((byte)-64)) >>> 6);
```

If bar is -128 then (int)bar is 0xFFFFFF80 which is then &'ed with 0xFFFFFFC0... which is: 0xFFFFFF80, you then shift that right 6 places to get: 0x3FFFFFFE

The right answer is really simple:

```
byte foo = (byte)((bar & 0xC0) >> 6);
```

bar is promoted to an int for the & operation so the only thing left in that int will be the top two bits of the original byte.  Then shift it right 6 bits and convert it back to bytes.

Comment: you say 0xC0, Jon says 0xD0. I think I shall have to check both your logic here...

Comment: @Martin: 0xC0 is correct. I've fixed my answer. How embarrassing :)

Comment: I was starting to reach that conclusion, I was onto triple checking it, never doubting the great Skeet! ;)