# Bit shift of signed byte strange behaviour

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation

I have written a function to print the bit out in a byte. This happens by setting the most significant bit to 1 comparing it to the inputbyte and if it is also 1 printing "1" else "0". The comparison byte is then shifted right.

How do I achieve starting with 10000000 and shifting to 01000000 then 00100000...

I believe my problem is caused by promotion to int then recasting but I don't see the solution.

```
package errorreporting;

public class ErrorReporting {

ErrorReporting() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ErrorReporting myError = new ErrorReporting();
    byte myByte = 16;
    myError.printByteArray(myByte);

}

public void printByteArray(byte inputByte) {
    // print out 1 or 0
    byte comparison = -128;
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        if ((inputByte & comparison) != 0) {
            System.out.print("1");
        } else {
            System.out.print("0");
        }
        //       System.out.print(" comparison : " + comparison);
        comparison = (byte) (comparison >>> 1);

    }
    System.out.println(" : " + inputByte);
}
```

}

This post has some info : [Java bitshift strangeness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173205/java-bitshift-strangeness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe my problem is caused by promotion to int then recasting

Yes, it is a combination of some implicit and explicit casting and sign extension:

1. All arguments are first promoted to int before the shift operation takes place, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3948303/1611055
2. Due to 1., your unsigned shift operator `>>>` does not help - it correctly shifts a `0` into the leftmost position, but since the source argument `-128` has been promoted to int **before** the shift is applied (resulting in `0xffffff80`), you end up with `0x7fffffc0` after the first shift.

The simplest solution is to use an `int` for your mask:

```
int comparison = 0x80;  // -128;
```

*Theoretically*, you could also still use a byte for the mask, but then you need to explicitly convert it to an `int` while discarding the sign bit at the same time, before applying the shift operator, like this:

```
byte comparison = -128;
...
comparison = (byte)( (((int) comparison) & 0xff) >>> 1);
```

`((int) comparison) & 0xff)` assumes that the byte should really be "unsigned" and converts it to the corresponding "unsigned" int value. Then, you can apply the shift operator (`>>` or `>>>` does not matter, since we have a positive `int` value in any case) and cast it back to a `byte`.

Comment: Thanks this works, I find it a bit annoying that Java does this auto promotion to int thing that makes bit wise operators behave not as expected, I wonder why they decided to do it like that.